# Is there a name for functions from $A^k$ to A?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there a name for functions whose domain is a cartesian product of the range?

If not, is there a name for functions whose domain is the same as the range?

Comment: Do you mean [idempotent matrices](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=idempotent+matrices&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)? Or, [idempotent functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Idempotent_functions)?

Comment: In general, if the domain is a $k$-fold product, it's called a "$k$-ary function". I don't know of any special name for when the domain is a power of the codomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call a function $A^k \to A$ a (total, $k$-ary) **operation** on $A$.

For example, we would say that addition is a binary operation on $\mathbb{R}$, since it defines a function
$${+} : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
For some other examples:

- Negation is a unary operation on $\mathbb{R}$;
- The [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product) is a ternary operation on $\mathbb{R}^3$;
- A single-sorted [algebraic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure), such as a group or a ring, is a set equipped with various operations $A^k \to A$ subject to equational axioms.

The word 'operation' has more general meanings than this, but if you qualify it with 'on $A$' then I don't think anyone would be confused.

A function whose domain is equal to its codomain, that is a function $A \to A$, is sometimes called an **endofunction**, or an **endomorphism** of $A$. Be careful using the word 'endomorphism' because that might suggest that the function preserves additional structure.